# std::map.count using c-strings does not work?

Tags: c++, string, dictionary

I wish to use c-strings instead of `std::string` for a performance situation. I have the following code:

```
std::map<const char*, int> myMap;
.
.
.
myMap.insert(std::pair<const char*, int>(str.c_str(), myint));
std::cout << myMap.count(str.c_str()) << std::endl;
```

Strangely enough the value I just entered returns 0 for `count()`?

Comment: Because it does NOT compare the strings you point to, it only compares the addresses of the pointers. If they point to the same text but in different parts of memory, it won't work. You could write a custom comparison function but I don't know it off the top of my head.

Comment: For your specific example, I would expect `c_str` to return the same pointer address in both calls IF you don't change str between them, but I don't know if this is guarnateed.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `std::map<std::string, int> myMap;` or even better use enum values as keys?

Comment: How do you expect to gain performance from using `const char*` instead of `std::string`?

Answer (score 4):

By default, `std::map` uses `std::less` to compare the keys (which is the same as `<`, really, except it's guaranteed to work on unrelated pointers too). Which means it just does pointer comparison, definitely not what you want.

Just use the C++11 string type (`std::string`) instead of a legacy type used for nul-terminated strings (`const char*`) and you'll be fine.

Comment: The suggestion to use `std::string` is good for many reasons: the lifetime of the keys is controlled by the map, and they really are immutable. A `const char*` can point to a string that can be changed by someone else, breaking the map.

Comment: `std::map` does *not* use `<`. It uses `std::less`. This makes a difference, at least in theory, because pointer comparison with `<` would not formally guarantee correct behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think using raw C strings will increase performance?

Anyway, `std::map` has no special treatment for `char` pointers. It treats them like any other kind of pointer and *not* like strings, which means that it simply compares the keys with `std::less`. Perhaps confusingly, this is different from the behaviour of C++ streams, which do behave in a special way when passed a `char const *`.

You'd get the same behaviour with something like `std::map<double *, int>`, `std::map<long *, int>` or `std::map<MyClass *, int>`. It's interesting to note that the pointer comparison works because `std::less` is guaranteed to work with pointers, even though pointer comparison with `<` is formally unspecified behaviour.

So, you are obviously not interested in comparing the pointer values directly. If you want lexicographical string comparison, you can specify the comparison for your map via the third template parameter:

```
std::map<char const *, int, RawPointerComparion>
```

What I called `RawPointerComparison` in this example must be a functor taking two pointers and returning whether the first is less than the second. You can use the `strcmp` C function for that. This should do the trick:

```
struct RawPointerComparison
{
    bool operator()(char const *lhs, char const *rhs) const
    {
        return strcmp(lhs, rhs) < 0;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use variable `str` to enter different strings in the map. For example

```
str = "first";
myMap.insert( { str.c_str(), 1 } );

str = "second";
myMap.insert( { str.c_str(), 2 } );

str = "first";
std::cout << myMap.count(str.c_str()) << std::endl;
```

In this case the first str.c_str() is not equal to the last str.c_str() (where you compare pointers to allocated strings) because different memory regions were allocated in these cases.

If you would do the following

```
str = "first";
myMap.insert( { str.c_str(), 1 } );
std::cout << myMap.count(str.c_str()) << std::endl;
```

without intermediate statements then the result would be the output 1.

It seems that you are doing what you do not want.:)